# How do I flag a query on Data Explorer?

Tags: support, flags, data-explorer

This [Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/147020/how-many-upvotes-you-require-for-a-gold-badge-for-a-specific-tag) doesn't even remotely do what it says

> -- How many upvotes you require for a gold badge for a specific tag
> -- This query returns the number of upvotes you require to get a gold badge for a specified tag.

And the query is

```
SELECT * FROM Badges 
WHERE UserId = ##UserId##
```

As you can see, that query is not right for that purpose. How do I flag it for attention?

Comment: I probably have a few dozen queries floating around which are at various intermediate stages of what I was doing (many not remotely close to the final product). And sometimes I just lost the plot, or copied another query for convenience, without changing the title. Some of these I have actually linked to so I wouldn't want them deleted (though I could see some value in having their title changed, but that's assuming whomever looks at it can actually figure out what's going on there, and someone cares enough to do so). All in all, this is a feature request, though I don't see it being accepted.

Comment: Thanks @Dukeling, it isn't a feature request. Just wanted to know how to do that but after this discussion I've come to know that it isn't necessary and those queries are not necessarily finished products always and there is no compulsion that they should hold true to what they say. Nothing else required.

Comment: Actually I was trying to say that there may be a feature request as an extension of this, as opposed to implying that you're requesting a feature (and said feature might be nice to have, in an ideal world, although I don't think it's very practical).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't flag them.

### False Advertising!

Users write the queries.

Users write the titles and descriptions.

Sometimes they are right.

Sometimes they are wrong.

Sometimes they are broken.

If users had to promise that their queries worked, I know I'd never post one there.

### Collaborative Creation

Who exactly do you think will fix it? [The guy who created it two and a half years ago and hasn't been seen in 2013?](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/5667/the-elite-gentleman) JQuery wielding Unicorns?

You can take that query, fork it, and make your own working query that does what it says. And then people will be happy. Or at least you'll be happy. And all is well with the world.

### Ain't Designed for Polish*

<sup>Polish, not Polish. Just to clear up any confusion. Though I doubt it supports Polish either.</sup>

Queries are saved all the time. And you can't mark them as final. And it's a separate account. And so you end up with a lot of flotsam lying around. And that's fine. It is what it is.

Relax. Crack open a beer. Learn some TSQL. It'll do you good.

### おまけ

Just for your special enjoyment, [I wrote you a working query that does exactly what it says](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/148056/183158/run-this-query-for-216). Sorta.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a query that a user started writing but abandoned (and there are probably tons of these). I don't think the Data Explorer was meant to be a repository of working (much less well-written) queries—the repository simply saves all queries that have been written.

I rely on the "favorited" count as a measure of quality. I'd be all for adding voting to queries, though—that way one can "flag" a non-working query by downvoting.

Answer (score 1):

We do not need to flag any query on Data SE. Users are free to create their own queries. If there is any mistake in the query feel free to edit it.

If you create a query it will be shown on here: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?order_by=recent. Also it shows all revisions of a single query. So you can't say that a user has created a wrong query because it's possible that he is editing and improving it. If you look at [that user's recent tab](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/5667/the-elite-gentleman?order_by=recent) you will see that query's other revisions.