# Why can't we vote for queries on data explorer?

Tags: feature-request, voting, data-explorer

Some queries are just plain wrong or unrecoverably badly written.
I'd like to be able to downvote these as a warning to others that might try to use them.

I'd also like to be able to upvote good queries. Although I can favourite them, that's not the opposite of a downvote, and should be reserved for "very good" queries IMHO.

Comment: Partial duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207508/152859

Answer (score 3):

The answer basically boils down to that the mechanism for identifying good queries (or warning others away from bad ones) hasn't really evolved along with the way queries now exist in Data Explorer.

As Shadow Wizard mentioned, favoriting is kind of meant to surface good queries to the top, but it's not necessarily the best indicator now. That said, there's some improvements to how queries are organized that I'd like to address before worrying about that (and maybe one of these days [support for comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87531/can-we-have-a-feature-to-allow-commenting-on-data-explorer-queries) will be added, which might help).

Comment: I thought of comments too - that might do the job. Especially because it could describe the problem so OP could fix the query

Answer (score 2):

I don't see much sense in voting on queries, either up or down.

Upvotes there are pretty much replaced by favorites: if one think a query is good he'll favorite it and unlike all other Stack Exchange sites, there is list of queries ordered by the amount of users who favorited.

As for bad queries you have a point there, but since nobody can delete queries (maybe a dev) better just leave them alone.

If you want only good queries, just browse [this list](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?order_by=favorite).

As for the "why" itself, Data Explorer is a standalone site which is not part of Stack Exchange and not using its "engine", just its data dump. So the whole voting system was not implemented by the person who created DE (Sam a.k.a waffles, former SE dev), and adding such thing is LOTS of work.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's because it's more like a playground than a real site maintained by moderators. Everybody can create a query no matter if

- it already exists or not
- it's not working
- other users can benefit from it
- ...

Personally, I didn't know about the site for a long time and now when I do, I still use it sparsely.