# Site for Stack Exchange queries

Tags: discussion, feature-request, data-explorer

This is more for a feature request. I would like to have queries at the same level as questions and answers in SE. I would like to be able to comment on them, vote them up and down, and notify the author if the query no longer works.

Comment: @NickStauner Not clear that this is a duplicate. The functionality to vote and comment on SEDE queries and to ping their authors is not available on Meta.SE, which is where the  answer there points. If the (sole) answer to another question does not answer the present one, it's not a duplicate.

Comment: Agree with @This, reopened now.

Comment: Related: [Can we have a feature to allow commenting on Data Explorer queries?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87531)

Comment: Related: [Why can't we vote for queries on data explorer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213650)

Comment: There's work to be done on query management, it's on my todo list.

Answer (score 2):

You can ask about them there, on Meta Stack Exchange (with [data-explorer](/questions/tagged/data-explorer) tag). Someone will provide an answer that created some query and you can upvote and downvote this answer, comment on them if something wrong, as you wish. For example [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231408/query-for-top-users-rep-over-the-past-n-days) asked to create a query is on-topic there, nobody closed it.

Comment: You might add that using the tag [tag:data-explorer] will attract the right crowd, like me.

Comment: @rene done, forgot to tell you ;-)